# SQL Query - SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with the below query. Basically the query below gives me all items from a ITEM_MASTER table, that are located at location '9999' from the ITEM_LOCATION table and that have a status of 'C' again in the ITEM_LOCATION table. I want to check if any of these items in the query below are also at any other location and have a status of 'A'.

So basically I want too cross reference the items from this query, to see if any of them also appear at any other location, not just 9999 and if they have a status of 'A'

```
SELECT IM.ITEM MIN,
   IM.ITEM_DESC,
   IL.ITEM MIN,
   IL.LOC,
   IL.STATUS
   FROM ITEM_MASTER IM,ITEM_LOC IL
   WHERE IM.ITEM_LEVEL = 2
   AND   IM.TRAN_LEVEL = 2
   AND IL.STATUS = 'C'
   AND IM.ITEM = IL.ITEM
   AND IL.LOC = 9999;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First, you should write your query using proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT IM.ITEM MIN, IM.ITEM_DESC,
       IL.ITEM MIN, IL.LOC, IL.STATUS
FROM ITEM_MASTER IM JOIN
     ITEM_LOC IL
     ON IM.ITEM = IL.ITEM
WHERE IM.ITEM_LEVEL = 2 AND IM.TRAN_LEVEL = 2 AND IL.STATUS = 'C' AND
      IL.LOC = 9999;
```

You can accomplish what you want with `exists`:

```
SELECT IM.ITEM MIN, IM.ITEM_DESC,
       IL.ITEM MIN, IL.LOC, IL.STATUS
FROM ITEM_MASTER IM JOIN
     ITEM_LOC IL
     ON IM.ITEM = IL.ITEM
WHERE IM.ITEM_LEVEL = 2 AND IM.TRAN_LEVEL = 2 AND IL.STATUS = 'C' AND
      IL.LOC = 9999 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM ITEM_MASTER IM2 JOIN
                   ITEM_LOC IL2
                   ON IM2.ITEM = IL2.ITEM
              WHERE IM2.ITEM = IM.ITEM AND
                    IL2.LOC <> 9999 AND
                    IL2.STATUS = 'A'
             );
```

Comment: I've been told to not use JOINS and to use Allas' instead

Comment: +1. Just two things : the `im2.Loc <> 9999` isn't needed, if I understand the question well (I think that only a stauts = 'A' should be checked, but I may be wrong). And the exists could maybe be in a case when in the select...

Comment: This is the correct answer and the correct way to do it. You can still alias the tables in the joins. Although @RaphaëlAlthaus is right, you don't need the <> 9999.

Comment: I get the following error when I try that;

ORA-00904: "IM2"."LOC": invalid identifier

00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

*Cause:   

*Action:

Error at Line: 16 Column: 5

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus . . . "at any other location . . . and if they have a status of 'A'".  I interpret this to mean that both fields need to be different.

Comment: @MarkLeslieNewsham-Kent: "*I've been told to not use JOINS*" - are you still using Oracle 9 or an even older version?

Comment: I've tried the above query and both my initial query and this one gives me 39,000 rows :/ Seems to be the same result